# How can I after cleaning a specific file mark it as modified or any label?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

In my project, There are more than 400 Java and XML files and I want to start to check all files to clean the codes (make my project more readable)

The question is how can I after cleaning a specific file mark it as modified or any label because there is a lot of files and maybe I return open the file that I clean it already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tools like CheckStyle or Sonar in your project with default or custom configuration and you will get a list of the files that didn't match your rules in the IDE, and you can refactor them, so you didn't need to mark them, you just need to check the files on the list

CheckStyle: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1065-checkstyle-idea

SonarLint : https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7973-sonarlint

Comment: These plugins work with Java files only. Are there plugins for XML files?

Comment: You are right i think SonarLint can but with some custom configurations, i will search for one that validate xml style and put it in comment